# Firebase Server Timestamp to Double iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`ServerValue.timestamp()` returns `[AnyHashable : Any]`. How to convert it to `Double`, so I could create a date with the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly how the Firebase timestamp works.

What it actually does is writes a timestamp to a node but you don't have access to it until after the write.

To get access to it, attach an observer to that node so when the timestamp is written, it will be returned in a snapshot.

So first we define a var

```
let kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp = [".sv":"timestamp"]
```

then attach an observer to a node so when the timestamp is written, we are notified of the event

```
func attachObserver() {

    let timestampRef = self.ref.child("timestamp")
    timestampRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
             let ts = snapshot.value as! //Int? Double? String?
             print(ts)
        }
    })
}
```

and the function that writes out the timestamp, causing the above observer to receive the event

```
func doTimestamp() {
    let timestampRef = self.ref.child("timestamp")
    timestampRef.setValue(kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp)
}
```

Hope that helps - if more info is needed, post a comment.

Comment: So the only way to get a serverstamp is firstly write it to the database, right? By the way your `doTimestamp()` function doesn' work. I used `func createTimestamp() {
  let timestampRef = self.ref.child("timestamp")
  timestampRef.setValue(ServerValue.timestamp())
 }`

Comment: @lysov What doesn't work. That's code that's been copied and pasted from a functiontional app. You have to remember to define kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp, write that to the node, which then fires the observer so the timestamp can be read in and used.